Does BeeWare Toga suports Android themes?
I started an Adroid app project with BeeWare and I want to customize my app theme in the /res/values/styles.xml using as a base <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">. Does BeeWare Toga will use the theme I buid or it has it's own color system ? I saw that I can specify styles for the widgets I create, but If I don't do it, will they use the theme style ? Does Toga widgets are wrapers for Android native ones or they are Toga specifics ? I've done some testing and it doesn't show the colors I set for all the attributes. Or maybe I don't know what to set... I used something like this... and altough I set colorPrimaryText to blue, all toga.Label texts are black...
Edit: In the mean time I find out that Toga on Android uses the native Android widgets so it means it must suport the Android themes. But now it will be good to know if it uses only the old AppCompat theme widgets or it has support for new MaterialComponents widgets too ?
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryText</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/backgroundColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColor</item>     
        
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/colorPrimaryText</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen_background</item>
    </style>
    
</resources>

